# Accessing xfig from x11 fails

Tags: x11, osx, dynamic-linking

I am trying to get access to xfig from x11 on my mac to draw some diagrams and including them in latex, but it shows the following error

```
bash-3.2$ xfig
dyld: Library not loaded: /opt/local/lib/libX11.6.dylib
  Referenced from: /opt/local/bin/xfig
  Reason: image not found
Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

Comment: This looks like x11 is not installed properly. Can you open any other x11 based programs?

Comment: @Ketan yes for example inkscape

Comment: How did you install xfig?

Comment: I installed it more than one year ago (i don't remember exactly) and it worked perfectly until I updated x11 few days ago, then the problem started ( it was originally a different problem, a problem was with display) . I thought if I remove and reinstalled x11 this might solve the problem but  it shows the above error. I believe I have removed some library files which i dont know exactly what are they.